# append csv files on column basis

Tags: python, bash, sed, awk, append

I'm trying to merge several CSV files, which have the configuration below:

```
File1

DATE;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,BE;
2014M02;0.9;1.5;
2014M01;-5.4;-4.4;
2013M11;-7.9;-9.2;
2013M10;-8.6;-14.0;


File2

DATE;BS-BYL,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-NAN,NSA,BAL,BE;
2014M02;1.5;6.7;
2014M01;-8.8;-4.4;
2013M11;-2.5;-9.6;
2013M10;-8.9;-11.4;
```

I want to merge them by columns, keeping the first column of File1 but removing the second column of File2. The desired output would be:

```
DATE;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,BE;BS-BYL,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-NAN,NSA,BAL,BE;
2014M02;0.9;1.5;0.9;1.5;
2014M01;-5.4;-4.4;-5.4;-4.4;
2013M11;-7.9;-9.2;-2.5;-9.6;
2013M10;-8.6;-14.0;-8.9;-11.4;
```

I was thinking of using `sed` but I'm not familiar with the use, especially in column. I thought the command `paste` but I could not find anything relevant with what I'm trying to do.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `join` command:

```
$ join -t\; -j 1 file1 file2 | sed 's/;;/;/g'
DATE;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,BE;BS-BYL,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-NAN,NSA,BAL,BE;
2014M02;0.9;1.5;1.5;6.7;
2014M01;-5.4;-4.4;-8.8;-4.4;
2013M11;-7.9;-9.2;-2.5;-9.6;
2013M10;-8.6;-14.0;-8.9;-11.4;
```

or if you don't want to pipe to `sed`, you can do (a little more verbose) by setting the output format:

```
$ join -t\; -j 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.2 2.3 2.4 file1 file2 
DATE;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,BE;BS-BYL,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-NAN,NSA,BAL,BE;
2014M02;0.9;1.5;1.5;6.7;
2014M01;-5.4;-4.4;-8.8;-4.4;
2013M11;-7.9;-9.2;-2.5;-9.6;
2013M10;-8.6;-14.0;-8.9;-11.4;
```

Comment: Hi Jaypal, your answer is fine. Thanks for that one.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk -F\; -v OFS=\; 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} {print a[$1]$2,$3}' file1 file2
DATE;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-ICI,NSA,BAL,BE;BS-BYL,NSA,BAL,AT;BS-NAN,NSA,BAL,BE
2014M02;0.9;1.5;1.5;6.7
2014M01;-5.4;-4.4;-8.8;-4.4
2013M11;-7.9;-9.2;-2.5;-9.6
2013M10;-8.6;-14.0;-8.9;-11.4
```

In your output example, you have some difference for `M02` and `M01`, maybe you write some wrong.